# Visual Web Part with Web Part Zones

Tags: web-part, content-editor-web-part, web-part-zone

I am trying to create a unique component that has two Content Editor Web Parts. One of these will contain embed code showing a video, while the other one will contain description as HTML.

The idea is to keep both controls separate, but treat this as a unique Web Part so adding it to different pages will be easier.

Adding a Web Part Zone to a Web Part sounds weird, but I tried it anyway and I keep getting different errors. Is this even possible?

Would this be possible using a User Control instead?

---

**UPDATE**

I have managed to add a CEWP to my Visual Web Part programmatically by adding the code below to the OnInit event:

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpmgr = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    XmlElement p = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("p");
    p.InnerText = "Hello World";
    ContentEditorWebPart cewp = new ContentEditorWebPart();
    cewp.Content = p;
    wpmgr.AddWebPart(cewp, String.Format("{0}_webPartZone", this.ID), 0);
    wpmgr.SaveChanges(cewp);
}

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

The isse now is that this is triggered every time the page loads, so a new CEWP is added to my page. How can I determine whether I already have a CEWP or not? Should I iterate through the WebParts on the SPLimitedWebPartManager?

Comment: Yes you can easily create a Visual Web Part and reference two Content Editor web parts inside it..

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I would really much appreciate if you could provide a link to any articles with further information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you tried is basically getting the current page's webpart manager and then adding new webpart to it.

The ideal solution to your problem is by extending `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` and overriding `CreateChildControls`

Here is one thread that explains this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419632/possible-to-load-a-web-part-inside-another

Comment: Thank you Amal. The issue I am facing now is that the CEWP if added programmatically, cannot be edited. Any thoughts on why is this happening?

Comment: I think you should change your approach and instead of using `Content Editor` try to use `RichHtmlEditor` control. This allows users to edit and add `HTML` information.

Comment: You mean a `RichHtmlField`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054020/using-rich-textbox-in-sharepoint-2013